# Spring Java, file not found when loading xml

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

So I followed a tutorial for Spring that I found online, namely a Hello World, and they have this structure at the end. I tried it and it worked fine, now I created a new Dynamic Web project, Eclipse doesn't seem to like this structure. I get:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring-Module.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

How do I fix this? Or rather, what's causing Eclipse to not know where the file is?

Error here:

[image: This one errors out]

Works here:

[image: Works here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `resources` folder is on classpath.
Project -> Properties -> Build Path -> Add folder